# Linq to Entity Query takes more than 2 minutes to execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, oracle11g

I am trying to perform the following query using LINQ to Entity and have a performance issue. It takes about 2-3 mins for the result to return. I need suggestions on how we can improve the performance of these queries

This is the method that I am using to bring the total number of orders between certain dates. The data is split between two tables here. I need to get the transaction numbers from one table and then using these transactions I am pulling out the orders and summing them up but the query is too slow for certain criteria where I have around 10k+ records returned in the first query.

```
public int GetOrderQuantity(List<int> TransactionNumbers, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
{
    List<int> transactions = _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTIONS.Where(trd => TransactionNumbers.Contains(trd.TRANSACTION_NUMBER) && trd.TRANSACTION_DATE >= FromDate && trd.TRANSACTION_DATE <= ToDate).Select(tr => tr.TRANSACTION_NUMBER).ToList();

    return _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTION_DETAILS.Where(trd => transactions.Contains(trd.TRANSACTION_NUMBER)).Select(tr => tr.PART_QTY).ToList().Sum();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `IQueryable<int> transactions = .... .Select(tr => tr.TRANSACTION_NUMBER)`? Without ToList() method, to prevent double selection from the database server.

Comment: If you execute the query twice, does it go fast the second time?

Comment: Do you really need 2 queries? Also approx how many items are in `TransactionNumbers` list?

Comment: @VMA will try this now

Comment: @Alexander Derck, No it doesn't, in fact the Db query executes in less than a second

Comment: @G1P That's what I mean, it's taking long because of your L2E being generated not because of the query itself. How many items are there in `TransactionNumbers`? I suspect that's your culprit

Comment: @Alexander Derck Transaction numbers are 16k roughly...

Comment: EF needs to build a query with those 16.000 values in it. Can't you put those values into a separate table with a foreign key to `RP_PART_TRANSACTIONS`?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck , both the tables already are separate as you can see in the query that I posted. we have transactions table and its details table

Comment: No, the List you pass as an argument `TransactionNumbers`, can't you put that in database so you can do inner join?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck , I know what you mean but I don't want to create an extra table. Ivan's third solution worked and is able to bring the 29k result set in less than 6 secs.   Many thanks for your suggestions  Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems in this code

```
List<int> transactions = _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTIONS.Where(trd => TransactionNumbers.Contains(trd.TRANSACTION_NUMBER) && trd.TRANSACTION_DATE >= FromDate && trd.TRANSACTION_DATE <= ToDate).Select(tr => tr.TRANSACTION_NUMBER).ToList();

return _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTION_DETAILS.Where(trd => transactions.Contains(trd.TRANSACTION_NUMBER)).Select(tr => tr.PART_QTY).ToList().Sum();
```

First, you use two queries which can be combined in one using `join` operator. Taking into account that the first query can return a lot of records (10K+ as you mentioned) and that using the in memory `Contains` inside the query cannot be processed **effectively** at database side, this might give you a big improvement.

Second, in the later query you use `ToList()` first, then `Sum`, which requires reading all the records from the database and summing them in memory. It would be much efficient to let database do the sum.

With all that being said, it's worth trying the following instead

```
var result =
    (from td in _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTION_DETAILS
     join t in _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTIONS
         on td.TRANSACTION_NUMBER equals t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER
     where TransactionNumbers.Contains(t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER)
         && t.TRANSACTION_DATE >= FromDate && t.TRANSACTION_DATE <= ToDate
     select td.PART_QTY)
    .Sum();
```

**Update:** Noticed from the comments that your `TransactionNumbers` contains ~16K items. **EF** will transform `TransactionNumbers.Contains(t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER)` part to a SQL `t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER IN (...)` clause with a 16K numbers listed in the `IN` clause, which will cause Oracle CBO to choose the full table scan and not the index scan. You may try forcing the index range scan by including the lower and upper bounds of the list like this

```
var minNumber = TransactionNumbers.Min();
var maxNumber = TransactionNumbers.Max();
var result =
    (from td in _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTION_DETAILS
     join t in _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTIONS
         on td.TRANSACTION_NUMBER equals t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER
     where t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER >= minNumber && t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER <= maxNumber
         && TransactionNumbers.Contains(t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER)
         && t.TRANSACTION_DATE >= FromDate && t.TRANSACTION_DATE <= ToDate
     select td.PART_QTY)
    .Sum();
```

If still slow, the last thing I can think of is to try doing as much as possible filtering/aggregating in the database (w/o `TransactionNumbers` filter) and then do the final filtering/aggregating in memory, like this

```
var query =
    from td in _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTION_DETAILS
    join t in _context.RP_PART_TRANSACTIONS
        on td.TRANSACTION_NUMBER equals t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER
    where t.TRANSACTION_DATE >= FromDate && t.TRANSACTION_DATE <= ToDate
    group td by t.TRANSACTION_NUMBER into g
    select new { TRANSACTION_NUMBER = g.Key, PART_QTY = g.Sum(td => td.PART_QTY) };

var filter = new HashSet<int>(TransactionNumbers); // For efficient lookup

var result = query.AsEnumerable() // Important! Switch to in memory context
    .Where(td => filter.Contains(td.TRANSACTION_NUMBER))
    .Sum(td => td.PART_QTY);
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, Just tried the query u mentioned above, it took more time than it was earlier. Took 181121 ms from postman

Comment: Did you look at the generated SQL. It highly depends of proper db indexes and the number of items in the `TransactionNumbers` list (see my comment). And of course the unstable Oracle cost based optimizer plan :(

Comment: I have not looked at the generated SQL though. I also have a unique index on the Transaction number and date combination

Comment: Try removing the `TransactionNumbers.Contains(...)` criteria and see what happens. It should process much more records, but if it runs faster, then the problem is in this type of filter, which is known to be ineffective in EF (and in general) - should really be SQL `IN (...)`.

Comment: If I remove it as mentioned by you, it's much quicker but that calculation is not correct as per the requirement you see

Comment: I know. It was suggested just temporary to identify what is causing the performance problem. Now at least we know that :)

Comment: Excellent Ivan the last approach worked like a charm..thanks